# Why abstract doGet into processRequest?

Tags: java

In the following example from the oracle controller example. They move all of the contents of doGet into another method. Why add this extra layer of abstraction ?

```
/** Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                     HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
  processRequest(request, response);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One might do so if one wanted to reuse request handling code for different request methods.  In particular, one might want to handle GET and POST requests very similarly, or even identically.  I cannot think of a good reason for such indirection that does not ultimately reduce to a consideration along those general lines.